# Jquery :not(this) unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Expectation:** Simple 4 line menu, on hover - all divs except the one hovered over with class `.snav` should lower `css font-size` to `5px`

**** OK PEOPLE - Yeah i know there is a CSS ONLY solution and I know other approaches for resolution -- let me clarify, I was just playing with Jquery selectors and methods, and the Jquery selector I commented out was EXPECTED to work as i listed above, it didn't so i changed it. my question was seeking an explanation for why that commented out selector FAILED ****

In looking at the structure and Jquery below, I expected both Jquery selector versions of the `.mouseover` to perform the same way, however the one commented out does not perform as expected. instead: It applies the font-size change to all .snav classes and does not exclude the (this) object as expected. I'm looking for someone to explain to me why one selector works but the other does not perform the same way.

```js
//$('.snav').mouseover(function() {
//    $('.snav:not(this)').css("font-size","5px"); 
//});

$('.snav').mouseover(function() {
    $('.snav').not($(this)).css("font-size","5px"); 
});

$('.snav').mouseout(function(){ 
    $('.snav').css("font-size","15px");
});
```

```css
.snav {font-size:15px; height:30px; line-height:30px;cursor:pointer;width:120px; border:thin solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <div id="nav1" class="snav">HOME</div>
  <div id="nav2" class="snav">PAGE 1</div>
  <div id="nav3" class="snav">PAGE 2</div>
  <div id="nav4" class="snav">PAGE 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The snippet works perfectly for me. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar - i know it works, but the Jquery selector thats commented out, does not work - i expected both versions of that selector to work identical. I was tying to figure out why the one commented out is not a proper working selector to get the same result.

Comment: @PraveenKumar that is because the failing code is commented out. I susspect is is because the `.not()` method JQuery adds extra logic to too allow such function where the selector `:not()` is just a css selector missing this extra functionality to understand what `this` means

Comment: `:not(this)` - `this` object cannot be resolved in the pseudo selector.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because you're using `this` as a string in the `:not()` selector, whereas you need to use the `this` keyword instead, to reference the element itself:

```
$('.snav').mouseover(function() {
    $('.snav').not(this).css("font-size", "5px"); 
});
```

That said, there's no need for Javascript here, you can achieve this in CSS alone:

```css
.snav {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
  border: thin solid black;
}
#menu:hover .snav {
  font-size: 5px;
}
#menu .snav:hover {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <div id="nav1" class="snav">HOME</div>
  <div id="nav2" class="snav">PAGE 1</div>
  <div id="nav3" class="snav">PAGE 2</div>
  <div id="nav4" class="snav">PAGE 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP was looking for an explanation why that specific selector was not working.

Comment: Nice css only solution but you should really give a reason to the issue as well as a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You've got `this` embedded in the string; it won't (and can't) be evaluated as `this` as it exists in the function.  Try

```
$('.snav').mouseover(function() {$('.snav').not(this).css("font-size","5px"); });
```

Inside jQuery/Sizzle or the browser's native `querySelectorAll()`, that string "this" is just the letters `t` `h` `i` `s`. That code has no way of knowing the value of `this` in your function. You simply cannot create a selector string that involves a DOM element reference directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` in a selector string.

The `this` keyword exists in JavaScript and references the current context where the code is running. There is no `this` keyword for CSS selectors, it doesn't know about the JavaScript context.